# The usage of Parameterized Scheduler in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized build which is described in the scripted pipeline.

I'd like to run it by a schedule with overridden parameters using the plugin:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin

I saw the example of using it in declarative pipeline:

```
triggers {
        cron('* * * * *')
        parameterizedCron('''
*/2 * * * * %GREETING=Hola;PLANET=Pluto
*/3 * * * * %PLANET=Mars
        ''')
    }
```

And here is how I tried using it in my script:

```
properties([
    disableConcurrentBuilds(),
    parameters(
        buildParameters()
    ),
    pipelineTriggers(
        [
            parameterizedCron('00 06 * * 1-5 %geb.env.browserName=chrome')
        ]
    )
])
```

But this trigger seems to be skipped without any exceptions or warnings. The build does not start on that time. What is the correct way to set it up in scripted pipeline?

I also would like to determine in further stages if the build was triggered via scheduler or manually - is there a way to do this? 
E.g. to print something like `"Triggered by CRON with parameters ${printenv}"` if it really was.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This syntax look correct.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to use parameterizedCron. The difference in my case was that I needed two different kinds of schedules and it was a bit tricky to figure out the correct syntax. Posting below the working solution in hopes to save you some time

```
    properties([
        parameters([
            string(name: 'schedule', defaultValue: 'linux', description: '...'),
            ]),    
        pipelineTriggers([
            parameterizedCron("${cronScheduleLinux} %schedule=linux\n${cronScheduleWindows} %schedule=windows")
        ])
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for some reason this doesn't work without jenkins restart. 
These steps solved the issue:

1. Start new build in order to obtain the latest script.
2. Restart jenkins: > service jenkins restart